# ERROR: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: windows_batch

Tags: chef-infra

I have a recipe that take a long time to execute (10 hours) and I am getting this error

ERROR: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: windows_batch

As you see, it is on a windows machine.

The recipe is

```
windows_batch "some_name" do
  code <<-EOH

    #copy code that takes several hours  

  EOH
  timeout = 180000
end
```

As you see, I have the timeout set to a big number but it timeouts around 6.5 hours and basically ignore mines.

The confusing part is that some nodes do not timeout although they are running exact same recipe!!!

How do I increase the timeout setting for this?

Comment: Are you sure you are using chef in a way it should be done? I cannot imagine a scenario in which I need to run some script that is executed several hours to __configure a system__. Obviously you should divide it into smaller parts, or create a *.bat file using chef and run it in some other (sub)process, not interacting with chef.

Comment: But I need chef to control the execution of this long script and only go to next step when this step this done. The script is really coping a lot of data from a remote location and I can't see why chef would not handle this. After all, chef is just running scripts.

Answer (score 0):

That code does not work... You don't use the `=`. Secondly, `timeout` isn't a valid attribute on the Windows Batch resource: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows/blob/master/providers/batch.rb#L34-L40.